# How to get external input value from Angular 2

Tags: angular, input

I'm developing an Angular 2 project that is integrated in an existing web app.
In this app there is an hidden input with a default value that I need to retrieve in my Angular project.
My problem is to access from Angular project to an external element. Is it possible to do it?
Is there a way to get value using jQuery? Or other way to do it?
I tested ElementRef but no results...
Thanks to everybody...

I try to give more detail:
my angular2 pages will be showed in an existing site in which there is an hidden input containing a token decrypted. I need to get the value in my Angular pages. I tried to use getElementById like a simple javascript instruction but it doesn't work. I also tried to use Element Reference:

```
import { ..., OnInit, ElementRef, AfterContentInit  } from '@angular/core';

constructor(..., private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

ngAfterContentInit() {
    var el = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getElementById('myInput');
    console.log(el)
}
```

I receive null value. Is this a wrong way to get the value? Is there an another way to do it?

Comment: passing value from backend to frontend ?

Comment: You can just use `document.getElementById('idToHiddenInput').value`

Comment: I need to do this operation in frontend. I tested document.getElementById but return null

Comment: @bigskull then you probably did something wrong, and without code there is no way to tell what

Comment: I simply tried: ngOnInit(): void {  var val = document.getElementById('myInput').value; console.log(val); } but return true